# Select multiple is not putting any values in the database or inserts only the last chosen

Tags: php, mysql, html, select, dropdown

I'm trying to make a select multiple (dropdown) list accept multiple values and insert them into a field in mysql database table, but the values aren't getting put into the field for some reason. I've researched this for hours, but none of the other questions relate exactly to my situation because I'm pulling the values dynamically another table in mysql database. The way the code is right now, I don't receive any error, but nothing is put into the database.

I've tried using statements such as `$_GET`, `foreach`, `if else`, `implode`, etc., but I must not be getting the syntax right because nothing seems to work. I've also tried taking the `[ ]` brackets out of the: `name='genretype[]` and `$genretype = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['genretype[]']);` lines, but when I do that I receive this error:

> mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

Can someone please take a look at this and let me know if you see what I'm doing wrong? (For your convenience I've only included code that relates directly to my issue. My other dropdown list that isn't selecting multiple, works perfectly.)

Top part of the php code:

```
// Check for a genre.
    if (empty($_POST['genretype'])) {
        $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter a genre.';
    } else {
        $genretype = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['genretype[]']);
    }

    if (empty($errors)) { // If everything's OK.
        // Add the movie to the database.
        // Check for existing record.
        $query = "SELECT id FROM dvd WHERE title='$title'";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) { // if there is no such movie title
        $query = "INSERT INTO dvd (title, numavail, categoryname, genretype)
            VALUES ('$title', '$numavail', '$categoryname', '$genretype')";
            // Make the query.
            $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
            if ($result) { // If it ran OK.
                echo "<p><b>Success! The new movie has been added.</b></p>";
                echo ('<p><div style="margin-top:30px;">');
                echo ('<span style="float:left;">');
                echo ('<FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="../dvd/index.php"><INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Back to DVDs" STYLE="margin:0px 15px 0px 0px;"></form></span></div></p>');
                echo ('<br style="clear:both;"></br>');

                exit();
            } else { // If it did not run OK.
                $errors[] = 'The movie could not be added due to a system error. We apologize for any inconvenience.'; // Public message.
                $errors[] = mysqli_error($dbc); // MySQL error message.
            }
```

Form part of the code:

```
<?php
            $ddlquery2 = "SELECT genretype FROM genre ORDER BY genretype ASC";
            $ddlresult2 = mysqli_query($dbc, $ddlquery2) or die("Bad SQL: $ddlquery");

            echo 'Genre (select all that apply): <select type="text" class="dropdown" name="genretype[]" multiple="multiple" size="5">';
            while($ddlrow2=mysqli_fetch_array($ddlresult2, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            echo "<option value='".$ddlrow2['genretype']."'>" . $ddlrow2['genretype'] . "</option>";
        }
            echo "</select>";
        ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, Kirk. I didn't know I could do that. I appreciate your advice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I didn't get any responses to my question, but I was able to figure it out for myself through trial and error, so I thought I'd share what fixed it.

I simply needed to change the code to the following.

The top part of the php code (I changed the line after `$genretype =` and removed the brackets after 'genretype' at the end of that line).

NEW 'WORKING' CODE:

```
// Check for a genre.
if (empty($_POST['genretype'])) {
    $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter a genre.';
} else {
    $genretype = implode(', ', (array)$_POST['genretype']);
}
```

Form part of the code (I changed most of the lines after the connection and query lines):

```
<?php
    $ddlquery2 = "SELECT genretype FROM genre ORDER BY genretype ASC";
    $ddlresult2 = mysqli_query($dbc, $ddlquery2) or die("Bad SQL: $ddlquery2");
    $match = "SELECT genretype FROM dvd WHERE id=$id";

    $numOpts = count($match);
    if ($numOpts>1){
    $matches=implode('","',$match);
    }elseif ($numOpts==1){
    $matches=$match;
    }else{
    $matches="";
    }

    echo 'Genre (select all that apply): <select name="genretype[]" multiple="multiple" size="5" class="multilist"';
    while($ddlrow2=mysqli_fetch_array($ddlresult2, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    echo "<option value='".$ddlrow2['genretype']."'>" . $ddlrow2['genretype'] . "</option>";
    }   
    echo "</select>";
?>
```